# can not fetch from database using mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)

Tags: php, html

I can not fetch rows from database and populate my select input

I have tried to populate the input by calling a function in another php file which fetches the result from the database and returns the result.

my function in getData.php:

```
function listTechnician(){
        global $conn;
        $position="technician";
        $sql="SELECT user.Name FROM user INNER JOIN user_account ON user.id = user_account.id WHERE user_account.position=$position";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("<script>console.log(".mysqli_error($result).")</script>");
        return mysqli_fetch_row($result) ;
    }
```

and my code in newAppModal.php(contains the select input to be populated):

```
<select class="form-control select2" id="appTime" name="appTechnician" required="">
                                    <?php 
                                    $data=listTechnician();
                                     while ($row=$data) {
                                    echo "<option>".$row['name']."</option>"; 
                                     }
                                    ?>
                                    <option selected="selected"></option>

                                    <option>Laboratory</option>


                                  </select>
```

this is contained in a modal

I want to populate my select input with the row fetched from database but it is giving me an error in the console like:

```
 main.js:388 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at listenBySelector (main.js:388)
    at Calendar.bindHandlers (main.js:6619)
    at Calendar.render (main.js:6595)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (receptionist1.php:66)
```

and i had a calendar which now doesn't appear

Comment: `return mysqli_fetch_row($result)` That's not `mysqli_fetch_assoc`. Furthermore, you're not sharing the JS that's generating that error. So is this a PHP error? A JS error?

Comment: It's a PHP error. Everything works fine when I remove the php  code fetching from database. And both 'mysqli_fetch_row' and mysqli_fetch_assoc do't work the sameway

Comment: PHP and Javascript run differently, and you don't show anything related to addEventListener. You need to do some more troubleshooting: Look at the source of the newAppModal.php to make sure everything is loaded there, check the Developer Console to see if there is any information there.

Comment: @A6du2 While that might be true, I generally expect a question about X function to include X function. I think you might need to look at the [mre] help page

Comment: @Machavity yes but I'm not using any javascript related to the error I'm getting. I'm using a calendar template that uses many packages in it's source. But I'll edit my question with all javascript code I have used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a couple of issues. Firstly, `listTechnician` is only fetching one row of data instead of all of them. Change

```
return mysqli_fetch_row($result) ;
```

to

```
return mysqli_fetch_all($result);
```

Secondly, you are not looping through the data properly in `newAppModal.php`. You should do something like this:

```
$data=listTechnician();
foreach ($data as $row) {
    echo "<option>".$row['Name']."</option>"; 
}
```

Note also that the field in your query will be called `Name` (not `name`); I have changed that in the above code too. It's possible the undefined index message for this is causing the problems with your Javascript.

Thirdly, in your SQL query, you need to enclose `$position` in single quotes i.e.

```
$sql="SELECT user.Name FROM user INNER JOIN user_account ON user.id = user_account.id WHERE user_account.position='$position'";
```

Comment: I have made all the edits you suggested but the problem is still there and found the  problem is actually in the $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die("<script>console.log('result error')</script>"); since it outputs result error in the console

Comment: @A6du2 you have a problem with the query string. see my edit.

Answer (score 0):

> Html Part  
>                                       ".$d.""; 
>                                     }
>
> ```
>                                 ?>
>
>
>                                 <option>Laboratory</option>
>
>
>                               </select>
> ```
>
> PHP function .
>
> function listTechnician(){
>         $mysqli_connection;          $mysqli_connection = new MySQLi('localhost', '', '', 'test');      if
>   ($mysqli_connection->connect_error) {
>            echo "Not connected, error: " . $mysqli_connection->connect_error;       }
>
> ```
>     $position="technician";
>     $sql="SELECT user.Name FROM user INNER JOIN user_account ON user.id = user_account.id WHERE user_account.position='$position'";
>     $result = mysqli_query($mysqli_connection, $sql) or die("<script>console.log(".mysqli_error($result).")</script>");
>           $data=array();      while ($row= mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {           $data = $row;
>
>   }       mysqli_close($mysqli_connection);       return $data;
>
> }
> ```
>
> > Blockquote

Comment: do not return  mysqli_fetch_row($result) directly you have to run loop in php funtion and make a data set and return the dataSet

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.co)

[image]m/M9mBa.png